# Why did Imperial Star Destroyers not have any anti-starfighter weaponry?

Tags: star-wars

In Star Wars Episode IV: A New Hope, we learn that the Empire doesn't consider a single man fighter to be any threat, even going so far as to barely send out any fighters to combat 20 or so Rebel fighters.

And then a single man fighter blows up their battlestation and a few million personnel with a lucky shot.

We also see that their Star Destroyers are updated in The Empire Strikes Back, but these still feature basically no anti-starfighter weaponry. After seeing how much damage starfighters alone could cause, it seems foolish to not at least have some.

Why did Imperial-II Star Destroyers not feature any anti-starfighter weaponry?

Comment: I don't know of any in-universe explanation (other than references from the EU about Imperial doctrine being to use overwhelming numbers of "disposable" fighters. OOU answers would be along the lines of, "It gave the rag-tag bunch of misfits fighting a vastly superior force a fighting chance, which makes a better story.

Comment: I would understand if they actually had overwhelming numbers in starfighters, but it seems like they never really did. Each SD only held 72 fighters, some of which were bombers, ill-equipped for dealing with fighters.

Comment: They did. They had turbo lasers, tractor weaponry and squadrons of TIEs. It's just that the Rebels would occasionally get lucky

Comment: Take a moment to consider Aircraft versus Ships (Destroyers and Carriers) - while the ships may *have* Anti-Air capabilities, launching Fighters is generally more effective

Comment: The only time I remember a statement like that was when they were specifically talking about the Death Star.  I don't remember anything similar being said about Star Destroyers.

Comment: @Chronocidal  The real world example involves airplanes traveling in air much faster than ships traveling on the surface on water, since air is a much less dense medium with less resistance than water.  Outer space is a vacuum with no resistance and thus no surface between mediums that have different resistances.  Thus there is no tactical use for one man fighters in space warfare.

Comment: A better example for this question would be the fate of the Executor. It took a kamikaze run from a single A-Wing (plus maybe the two who took out the shield generator/radar dome) to make it fall out of the sky and on top of DS2, in zero gravity. Ships can hardly get more vulnerable than that.

Comment: @M.A.Golding From `F=ma`, it is possible for a 1-man light-fighter to accelerate and manoeuvre far more efficiently than a Star Destroyer (similar to the Square-Cube Law).  It *also* presents a far smaller and harder to hit target.

Comment: It's my general understanding that turbolasers are not terribly effective against starfighters. The real world equivalent would be shooting planes with the main guns on a battleship. Laser cannons were generally used to ward off starfighters, and SDs had none of that. And 72 disposable fighters isn't much when a Mon Cal cruiser can bring in over a hundred, though I don't know when they were first encountered.

Answer (score 5):

The in universe explanation is that the rebels got lucky/were just that good I suppose

Star destroyers are formidable things as per their specifications here

> Imperial II-class Star Destroyer
>
> TECHNICAL SPECIFICATIONS
>
> LENGTH
>
> - 1,600 meters
>
> MGLT
>
> - 60 MGLT
>
> MAXIMUM ATMOSPHERIC SPEED
>
> - 975 kilometers per hour
>
> ENGINE UNIT(S)
>
> - KDY Destroyer-I ion engines (3)
> - Cygnus Spaceworks Gemon-4 ion engines (4) (emergency use)
>
> HYPERDRIVE RATING
>
> - Class 2 (primary)
> - Class 8 (backup)
>
> HYPERDRIVE SYSTEM
>
> - Equipped
>
> POWER PLANT
>
> - Solar ionization reactor
>
> SHIELDING
>
> - Deflector shield generator domes (2)
>
> SENSOR SYSTEMS
>
> - Long range sensor
>
> ARMAMENT
>
> - Turbolaser batteries (60)
> - Heavy ion cannon emplacements (60)
> - Tractor beam projectors (10)
>
> COMPLEMENT
>
> - TIE line starfighters (72), usually:
> - TIE/ln space superiority starfighters (48)
> - TIE/sa bombers (12)
> - TIE/IN interceptors (12)
> - All Terrain Armored Transports (20)
> - All Terrain Scout Transports (30)
> - At least 2 Gozanti-class cruisers
> - Lambda-class T-4a shuttles (8)
>
> DOCKING BAYS
>
> - At least 2
>
> CREW
>
> - Officers (9,200)
> - Enlisted crew (27,850)
>
> PASSENGERS
>
> - Stormtroopers (9,700)
>
> CONSUMABLES
>
> - 2 years
>
> COMMUNICATION SYSTEMS
>
> - Communications tower
>
> OTHER SYSTEMS
>
> - Internal defences
>
> <sub><sup>https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Imperial_II-class_Star_Destroyer</sup></sub>

The OOU is simply that we were only shown a tiny cross section of battles that likely occured across the empire. You can't build an empire at all without winning fights after all

So I suspect they won a lot more than they lost.

I'll add to my answer part of Chronocidal's comment to your question, Fighters ARE anti fighter weaponry and as you can see the Star Destroyer has a decent complement.

Comment: It's as if a thousand readers cried out in terror and were suddenly silenced.